# Which datatype property to reuse for "deleted_at"?

Tags: rdf, owl, dublin-core

I'm converting some social media data sets to RDF. I try to use only popular ontologies/vocabularies. So far SIOC, FOAF, Dublin Core and SKOS are sufficient. But now I need a datatype property to link a post URI with the date it is deleted (well, marked as deleted in fact). There are `dcterms:created` and `dcterms:modified` but nothing about deleted, which I guess is natural - if it is actually deleted there is nothing to link it with. Now I'm considering `dcterms:valid`but I'm hoping there could be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

I think that some of the DC properties are probably applicable.  The documentation for some of them say that they take dates *or ranges*.  If you have a begin and end date, it seems like you can put them together to make a range.  E.g,. the documentation for **available** and **date** say:

> available URI:    http://purl.org/dc/terms/available
>   Label:    Date Available
>   Definition:   Date (often a range) that the
>   resource became or will become available.

> URI:  http://purl.org/dc/terms/date
>   Label:  Date
>   Definition: A point or period of time associated with an event in the lifecycle of the
>   resource.

There's also a **temporal** property that might be helpful (but I'm not sure exactly how it's supposed to be used):

> Term Name:    temporal
>   URI:    http://purl.org/dc/terms/temporal
>   Label:  Temporal Coverage
>   Definition:     Temporal characteristics of the resource.
>   Type of Term:   Property
>   Refines:    http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/coverage
>   Refines:    http://purl.org/dc/terms/coverage
>   Has Range:  http://purl.org/dc/terms/PeriodOfTime

That suggests that **coverage** might be of interest, too, and that you'll want to look at what a **PeriodOfTime** is.